# wxWidgets and X11 issues in Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, x11, codeblocks

I'm trying to make a simple Dialog Based GUI using wxWidgets. I am using X11/Xlib.h for image capturing (printscreen). Problems start when I change anything in GUI using wxSmith (e.g. drag and drop new button) because it automatically changes button names to Button1,Button2...

```
Button1 = new wxButton(this, ID_BUTTON1, _("About"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, wxDefaultValidator, _T("ID_BUTTON1"));
```

Problem is that Button1..5 are already defined in X.h:

```
/* button names. Used as arguments to GrabButton and as detail in ButtonPress
   and ButtonRelease events.  Not to be confused with button masks above.
   Note that 0 is already defined above as "AnyButton".  */

#define Button1         1
#define Button2         2
#define Button3         3
#define Button4         4
#define Button5         5
```

Can I somehow modify wxWidgets not to automatically change names or just to add my custom prefix e.g. somethingButton1?

Comment: "Problems start when I change anything in GUI using wxSmith (e.g. drag and drop new button) because it automatically changes button names to Button1,Button2..." — Out of curiosity I have installed Code::Blocks and tried to use drag-n-drop with wxSmith. Nothing of this sort happens. Buttons with custom names remain with their names, new buttons are named Button{123...}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you changing the var name in the GUI designer, or editing the cpp file directly?

If you edit stuff between `//(*Initialize(PanelName)` and `//*)` in the cpp then any changes you make will be wiped out (not just the change to the button name).

If you are looking at the Resources tab (which you should be if you're using the Drag 'n Drop), below it is the properties of the currently selected button (or other widget).  Change the `Var name` property to `myButton1` to change the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you can simply write

```
myButton1 = new wxButton(this, ID_BUTTON1, _("About"), ....
```

I see that you are using wxSmith, a Rapid Application Developer (RAD) plugin for CodeBlocks.  This means that you are relying on a computer program to write your code for you, which is something that has never worked well for all the decades of effort.

My advice would be, best first:

1. Take a deep breath and write your own code.  You will learn a lot!
2. Choose another RAD.  There are many [available](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Comparison_of_wxSmith_features) and some should be more sophisticated and adapted to running with X11.
3. Download the wxSmith code.  Do a global find & replace Button1 -> wxSmith_Button1.  Rebuild.

Comment: Yes, but I have to do that every time I change something about GUI, so I'm looking for simpler solution if there is one.

Comment: Please explain more!  You have to write code to 'change something' - you cannot change things by just wishing at them.

Comment: I change it by changing design form e.g. using drag and drop for button, not coding.

Comment: Still not sure what your question is about.  Sounds a bit like you are using some 'mickey-mouse' dialog layout app.  Those things are no use for anything more than toy programs.  To build and maintain a real, useful app, you need to write code.  IMHO

Comment: If you want to get a useful answer, please specify what form designer you are using, so the experts in that can help you out.

Comment: Thanks, did that (wxSmith btw).